# Generate double digits from 00 to 24

Tags: python

I have date string such as `2016-01-01` and I want to generate `HH:MM:SS` and add to it such that it becomes:`%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`. So now I need to generate random Hour, Minutes and Seconds, or how to generate double digits: `randint(00, 24)` i.e. `00, 06, 09` instead of `0, 6, 9`?

Comment: Just generate normal numbers, put them into a `datetime`, and use `.strftime` to make your full date string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast a string from the integer "myinteger" with:

```
"{:02d}".format(myinteger)
```

this way it will always show at least 2 numbers (00,01, ... , 09, 10, ... 100, ...)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question, to pad numbers with 0 you can just use `string.zfill(n)` where `n` is the minimum amount of chars required. Example:

```
from random import random
import math

num = math.floor(random() * 24)
num = str(int(num))
print num.zfill(2) # => random num between 00 and 23
```

But, looks like you just need to parse a date and output a datetime - which should be done more like this:

```
import time
dt = '2016-01-01'

print time.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

And you can modify the date as an object and show/parse whatever details you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can format display of integer value like this

```
"%.2d" % (int_value)
```

In example, following code:

```
print "%.2d" % 2
```

displays

```
02
```